# How to find azure AD guest user invitation has redeemed or not using Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

I need to find whether the Guest user has redeemed the invitation or not. When I get the user details from Graph API the returned user doesn't has that kind of information.

But in the Azure Portal I can see the source property under the Identity section is getting changed to Microsoft Account or something like that from "Invited user" when the user redeem the invitation.

Comment: Seems like you could get the invitation status: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/invitation

Comment: @juunas we are getting this status at the time we send invitation. But I didn't find a way to retrieve it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the extensionproperty on the azureaduser... it has the userstate for the invitation.

Example:

```
(Get-AzureADUser -SearchString 'insertusername').ExtensionProperty
```

the Extension Property shows: `SEE USERSTATE "pendingacceptance"`

```
Key                         Value                           
---                         -----                           
odata.type                  Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User
ageGroup                                                    
consentProvidedForMinor                                     
createdDateTime             7/09/2018 6:49:38 AM            
employeeId                                                  
legalAgeGroupClassification                                 
onPremisesDistinguishedName                                 
userIdentities              []                              
userState                   PendingAcceptance               
userStateChangedOn          7/09/2018 6:49:35 AM
```

Comment: They have added the feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/customize-invitation-api#invitation-status